# Creating a custom link in a custom plugin in BuildFire myPlugin SDK

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to create a link in buildfire index.html

```
<a href="DEEPLINKURL">Home</a>
<a href="DEEPLINKURL">About</a>
<a href="DEEPLINKURL">Contact Us</a>
```

but it doesn't seem to work using the 
the DeepLinkurl is generated by the feature

e.g.

```
 <a href="app7XXXXX://plugin/XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX">Home</a>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? If you are trying to navigate from within the app to another plugin in the app there is an easier way. If you're trying to deep-link into a plugin within the app from somewhere external like an email there are some specifications you need to follow.

Comment: i am trying to navigate within the app to another plugin

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is have the Control side of your plugin select which other plugins you want to navigate to using

`buildfire.pluginInstance.showDialog(options, callback)`

ref: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Plugin-Instances#buildfireplugininstanceshowdialogoptions-callback

Save the object returned into DataStore or whatever database you are using. Then when you actually want to navigate use this

`buildfire.navigation.navigateTo (pluginData)`

ref: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationnavigateto-plugindata